# invalid argument (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.77)

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

i have this error

invalid argument (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.77)

when if try

```
$browser->visit('/');
```

but when i try

```
$browser->visit('https://www.google.com');
```

there is no any error

```
    $process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
    $process->start();
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless']);
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
    $driver = retry(5, function () use($capabilities) {
        return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities);
    }, 50);
    $browser = new Browser($driver);
// $browser->visit('https://www.google.com');
$browser->visit('/');
$browser->screenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/'.date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.png'));
$browser->quit();
$process->stop();
```

- Dusk Version: ^6.15
- Laravel Version: ^8.12
- PHP Version: 8.0.3

Comment: Make sure your root url is set correctly via e.g. the environment variable `APP_URL` either in your corresponding .env file or in phpunit.xml

Comment: I'm sure url is the same 

Development Server (http://appcubes.test:8000) started
APP_URL=http://appcubes.test:8000

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help that the documentation for Dusk is about as bad the developer debugging experience for it is - it's almost as if the devs don't want you to be testing your apps - but for whatever reason I found this buried as an "aside" [under the documentation's CI/CD section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#continuous-integration):

> Most Dusk continuous integration configurations expect your Laravel application to be served using the built-in PHP development server on port 8000. Therefore, before continuing, you should ensure that your continuous integration environment has an APP_URL environment variable value of http://127.0.0.1:8000.

I therefore added `APP_URL=localhost:8000` to my `.env.dusk.local` file (again, nothing really to do with CI/CD):

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=localhost.rc:8000
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/test_db.sqlite
```

...and sure enough it does fix the error.